# Has Google pushed an update to their OAuth2.0 flow that breaks multiple accounts?

Tags: oauth

Up until last week, when ever I was logged into multiple accounts in Google and I invoked the OAuth2.0 flow I would get to an ugly screen (looked like it had been hit repeatedly with the ugly stick) that was functional. It would display a list of radio buttons with all the accounts I am logged in as, you select the one and continue through the flow.

This week I now get a [beautiful screen that is non-functional](http://grab.by/g9FI) (does not list accounts and the signin button only adds an additional account to the list of accounts I am signed in as) I should point out that I am logged into 4 different Google accounts at the same time. The OAuth2.0 for my app appears to be working fine as if I start an in-cognito window in Chrome, or start a new session and only have one account logged in, my OAuth flow continues normally.

Is this just me or is everyone hit by it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're also experiencing this. Hope someone at Google takes note and gets this fixed soon!

EDIT: To clarify, I've only experienced the problem when logged into both a personal Google account AND a Google apps account. Haven't tested other situations at present.

Comment: We have notified some contacts at Google... hopefully they will have some influence as those contacts are also using Google's OAuth (but probably only with 1 account logged in ;-) )

Answer (score 6):

We (google) are rolling back the new page and within a few minutes it should return to the previous behavior.

Any chance you could let us know what kinds of accounts those 4 you were logged in to were? SAML? Google Apps? Plain gmail?

Comment: A plain gmail account, my cloudbees account, and two other domain email accounts for other domains I own where gmail is the mail server. The cloudbees account is also a GAE account and my gmail might be one too

Comment: Thanks, with that info we've reproduced the issue and we'll be trying again to deploy the prettier UI soon.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, we just rolled out the new UI, so you may begin to see the "beautiful screen" that is now functional. :-) Thanks for the bug report.

Comment: Yes it looks lovely now... and more importantly too it works!