# Bug in Google OAuth2 UI for users who are logged into multiple accounts?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has Google pushed an update to their OAuth2.0 flow that breaks multiple accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478524/has-google-pushed-an-update-to-their-oauth2-0-flow-that-breaks-multiple-accounts)

Implementing OAuth2 authentication with Google using Passport.js.  I can authenticate fine if I'm logged into just one Gmail account.

But if I'm logged into two Google accounts at the same time, then the expected behavior is for the Google landing page to ask me which account I want use (e.g. "formal_me@gmail.com" or "casual_me@gmail.com").  I've seen it work like that in the past.

However, now the page fails to list the accounts.  The page says "Select an account" but not listing what I'm signed into.

It fails in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.  And I see it just now even when I logout and 
[log back in to StackOverflow via Google](https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=lso&continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?zt=ChRuaXhYeF9MakZHRFFaVEtZaEduMhIfa3NDQzZiY0Q1ZWdRc2hRVjBpZVpEQXB5UEZtX2N3SQ%25E2%2588%2599APsBz4gAAAAAUFoKX6Nl1llcEK9UkFGzjFaguf-nL8YH&from_login=1&hl=en&as=-48f823099fff68f0&btmpl=authsub) (again, only if logged into multiple Google accounts).

It fails on  AccountChooser.js:1444, and specifically is not able to find the element 'account-list':

`[AccountChooser.js:1944]`  `document.getElementById('account-list').getElementsByTagName')`

So presumably this is a small recent bug in Google's OAuth2 code.

Is there a place to report?  Or might there be a way to work around?  At the least, this is a note in case someone else experiences this.

Comment: Certainly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12478524/1467115.

Comment: You're right.  I had searched but somehow missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We (Google) noticed this bug in our new page and already rolled it back. New page will be displayed again later next week with this bug fixed.

Comment: Holy smokes that was fast.  Should I delete this post?